# How to find a predecessor and successor of an element from mysql table?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have a table named student in mysql database as below.

```
name value
sdf  -3
abc   3   
ddf   4
sdf   7
```

Given a value, I should be able to find the closest values to it, but one is lesser and the other is greater.

For ex: given 3, output should be -3 and 4

I have a solution something like:

```
(select value from student where value>3 order by value desc limit 1)
union
(select value from student where value<3 order by value desc limit 1)
```

But I want a query which can efficiently traverse the table once and produce the result. Can you help me find it?

Comment: the table size will be in lakhs and I can't alter the table as I have  only read permission.

Comment: I like your solution

Comment: Are you on Postgresl or mysql?  if on postgresql you can use a window function to create a ROW_NUMER or DENSE_RANK (in case there are repetitive values) and then do self joins to get the ancestor and predecessor.....

Comment: You just need an index on `value` and your sollution will be fast. There is probably no faster way.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work but it's sure it does only scan

```
SELECT max(if(value < 3, value, NULL)) AS predecessor,
       min(if(value > 3, value, NULL)) AS successor
FROM TABLE;
```

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh), lakhs is ~10^5 rows. On modern hardwares, you should be fine. Test on a MacBook pro:

```
mysql> SELECT max(if(value < 3, value, NULL)) AS predecessor,        min(if(value > 3, value, NULL)) AS successor FROM toto;
+-------------+-----------+
| predecessor | successor |
+-------------+-----------+
|           2 |         4 |
+-------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.35 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from toto;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  1000004 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.23 sec)
```

Comment: @Thomas Thank you, I'm looking for the same kind of query.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Postgressql, Oracle, or sql-server this should work and ignore if value is duplicated

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT
    *
    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY value ASC) AS Rank
  FROM
    Tbl
)

SELECT
  c.name
  ,c.value
  ,p.value AS Predesessor
  ,s.value AS Successor
FROM
  cte c
  LEFT JOIN cte s
  ON (c.Rank + 1) = s.Rank
  LEFT JOIN cte p
  ON (c.Rank - 1) = p.Rank
```

Comment: -Joining a table would be worse as computation involves lakhs* lakhs* lakhs . In that case my solution would be faster which is just 2*lakhs

Comment: I would suggest you look at execution plans.  For your results you would be looking 1 query with 2 sub selects for the columns.  yours would have to be applied 2 sub selects for every row.  Union is also like using group by so you wouldn't even get the results you say you want from your query. which I suspect is why you asked the question to begin with.  Don't worry I won't bother helping anymore

Comment: -My apologies, if my comment would have hurt you.